# Perl cannot locate module in @INC

Tags: linux, perl, redhat

I am running Centos 6.4 and perl 5.10. I have short script which uses the `DateTime` module. However when I run my script I get the following error message telling me various modules cannot be located as they are not in the library path.

```
Can't locate Params/Validate.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at /usr/lib64/perl5/DateTime/Duration.pm line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib64/perl5/DateTime/Duration.pm line 11.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib64/perl5/DateTime.pm line 45.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib64/perl5/DateTime.pm line 45.
Compilation failed in require at ./jr_fix_western_filestore.perl line 39.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./jr_fix_western_filestore.perl line 39.
```

All of these packages have been installed via yum. eg `yum install perl-Params-Validate.x86_64` and `yum install perl-DateTime.x86_64`. Should the yum install not place these modules in @INC?

I have also tried to install the packages via cpan but this seems to want to download lots of dependencies first and inevitably fails.

```
  CPAN.pm: Going to build D/DR/DROLSKY/DateTime-1.03.tar.gz

Can't locate Module/Build.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at Build.PL line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Build.PL line 5.
Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Build.PL --installdirs site]
Warning (usually harmless): 'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
  DROLSKY/DateTime-1.03.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Build.PL --installdirs site -- NOT OK
Running Build test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running Build install
  Make had some problems, won't install
Could not read '/root/.cpan/build/DateTime-1.03-Brpqo5/META.yml'. Falling back to other methods to determine prerequisites
  Warning: CPAN.pm discovered Module::Build as undeclared prerequisite.
  Adding it now as such.
```

When I try to install Module::Build in cpan, I get the following error

```
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Failed during this command:
 OVID/Test-Harness-3.28.tar.gz                : make_test NO
 MSCHWERN/Test-Simple-0.98.tar.gz             : make_test NO
 JPEACOCK/version-0.9902.tar.gz               : make_test NO
 BOBTFISH/Module-Metadata-1.000014.tar.gz     : make_test NO
 DAGOLDEN/CPAN-Meta-YAML-0.008.tar.gz         : make_test NO
 MAKAMAKA/JSON-PP-2.27202.tar.gz              : make_test NO
 DAGOLDEN/Parse-CPAN-Meta-1.4404.tar.gz       : make_test NO
 DAGOLDEN/CPAN-Meta-Requirements-2.122.tar.gz : make_test NO
 DAGOLDEN/CPAN-Meta-2.130880.tar.gz           : make_test NO
 DAGOLDEN/Perl-OSType-1.003.tar.gz            : make_test NO
 JESSE/Locale-Maketext-Simple-0.21.tar.gz     : make_test NO
 BINGOS/Params-Check-0.36.tar.gz              : make_test NO
 BINGOS/Module-Load-0.24.tar.gz               : make_test NO
 BINGOS/Module-CoreList-2.91.tar.gz           : make_test NO
 BINGOS/Module-Load-Conditional-0.54.tar.gz   : make_test NO
 BINGOS/IPC-Cmd-0.80.tar.gz                   : make_test NO
 DAGOLDEN/ExtUtils-CBuilder-0.280205.tar.gz   : make_test NO
 LEONT/Module-Build-0.4005.tar.gz             : make NO
```

Any pointers?

---

`rpm -ql perl-Params-Validate` returns

```
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Attribute
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Attribute/Params
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Attribute/Params/Validate.pm
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Params
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Params/Validate.pm
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Params/ValidatePP.pm
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Params/ValidateXS.pm
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Params
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Params/Validate
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Params/Validate/Validate.bs
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Params/Validate/Validate.so
/usr/share/doc/perl-Params-Validate-0.95
/usr/share/doc/perl-Params-Validate-0.95/Changes
/usr/share/doc/perl-Params-Validate-0.95/LICENSE
/usr/share/doc/perl-Params-Validate-0.95/MANIFEST
/usr/share/doc/perl-Params-Validate-0.95/META.yml
/usr/share/doc/perl-Params-Validate-0.95/README
/usr/share/doc/perl-Params-Validate-0.95/TODO
/usr/share/man/man3/Attribute::Params::Validate.3pm.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/Params::Validate.3pm.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/Params::ValidatePP.3pm.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/Params::ValidateXS.3pm.gz
```

I'm not sure if these paths are searched by @INC

However `locate Validate.pm` returns nothing

Comment: check where *yum* installs the package.

Comment: `rpm -ql perl-Params-Validate`, plus do you have make installed (`yum groupinstall "Development Tools"`)?

Comment: to check where packages are, try using `locate` in the terminal. E.g. check `locate Validate.pm`

Comment: Err... No! Don't try locate. It may not be installed and its database might not be up to date. Like Xaerxess said, use `rpm -ql` to find out where it was installed to.

Comment: Question updated with rpm -ql output. Does this correlate with @INC?

Comment: @Xaerxess I haven't installed the development tools. I tried but receive dependency resolution errors relatting to git ??? `Error: Package: git-1.7.10.1-1.el4.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.4()(64bit)
Error: Package: git-1.7.10.1-1.el4.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Requires: libcurl.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: git-1.7.10.1-1.el4.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Requires: libssl.so.4()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest`

Comment: The output of `rpm -ql` clearly shows that the package you installed is a perl 5.8 package. However, you told us you were using 5.10. Weird.

Comment: It seems that you don't have RHEL 6 but 5 which has perl 5.8 as default. What is the output of `perl --version`? Also, you have quite a mess with installed packages...

Comment: @Xaerxess perl --version is v5.10.1. I am actually using centos 6.4 rather than redhat. Confusing my laptop and desktop. Howdo I clean up the installed packages?

Comment: @innaM I am using perl 5.10. I have noticed packages being installed in /vendor_perl/perl_5.8 on my rhel 6.4 desktop also. Is there any way I can include vendor_perl/perl_5.8 in my INC. I'm puzzled how I can solve this issue. Maybe I should use perlbrew

Comment: try ``perl -e 'use 5.8.5; use DateTime;'``

Comment: This may be the issue. When trying ` yum install perl-Params-Validate.x86_64` it gives the following `=======================================================================================
 Package                     Arch          Version               Repository       Size
=======================================================================================
Installing:
 perl-Params-Validate        x86_64        0.95-1.el4.rf         rpmforge        114 k

Transaction Summary
=======================================================================================` This seems a v old version

Comment: `perl -V` will answer your last question as to whether those directories are searched.

Comment: That `locate Validate.pm` shows nothing may only indicate that your locate database hasn't been updated since those files were installed.  You can use 'updatedb' or the like to fix that, or you can just `find /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl -name Validate.pm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you have RPMforge configured for RHEL / Centos 4 but you use Centos 6:

> Installing: perl-Params-Validate x86_64 0.95-1.**el4**.rf

Follow the instructions from [this site](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge) and do global dist upgrade to fix broken dependencies (I you're lucky reinstall won't be needed). Then install perl packages you want.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers The page it links to currently says "RPMForge/RepoForge is a dead project. It is not maintained. DO NOT USE." - see https://github.com/repoforge/rpms/issues/375. I guess one should completely abandon RPMForge. For historical purposes, [Web Archive can be used](http://web.archive.org/web/20160727041758/https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge) to see what was on that page.

Answer (score 4):

search and install

```
 yum install perl-CGI
```

this worked for me.,

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the discussion, but had the same problem.  Here is how I solved it.

CPAN was giving me the same error because an older version of was installed under yum.  I updated the package via yum and was able to move forward.