# Can't locate Email/Sender/Transport/SMTP/TLS.pm in @INC

Tags: perl

I am installing FreeSide on Ubuntu 10.4, everything prior to the install goes fine, but once I get to the actual install, I get these errors:

```
Can't locate Email/Sender/Transport/SMTP/TLS.pm in @INC
(@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1
/usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 /usr/share/perl/5.10 
/usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/Misc.pm line 100.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/Misc.pm line 100.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/cust_bill.pm line 16.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/cust_bill.pm line 16.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/cust_main/Billing.pm line 10.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/cust_main/Billing.pm line 10.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 19) line 3.
    ...propagated at /usr/share/perl/5.10/base.pm line 93.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/cust_main.pm line 10.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/agent.pm line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/agent.pm line 8.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/access_groupagent.pm line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/access_groupagent.pm line 6.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/access_group.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/access_group.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/access_usergroup.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/access_usergroup.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/access_user.pm line 10.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/access_user.pm line 10.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/otaker_Mixin.pm line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/otaker_Mixin.pm line 6.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 15) line 3.
    ...propagated at /usr/share/perl/5.10/base.pm line 93.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/cust_pkg.pm line 5.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/cust_svc.pm line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/cust_svc.pm line 9.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/queue.pm line 14.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/queue.pm line 14.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/part_export.pm line 14.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/part_export.pm line 14.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/part_svc.pm line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/part_svc.pm line 9.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/pkg_svc.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/pkg_svc.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/part_pkg.pm line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/FS/part_pkg.pm line 11.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/bin/freeside-setup line 10.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/bin/freeside-setup line 10.
```

I've tried installing [Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP::TLS](https://metacpan.org/module/Email%3a%3aSender%3a%3aTransport%3a%3aSMTP%3a%3aTLS) using cpan, but I can't tell if it worked.

This program is mostly written in Perl, which I know virtually nothing about.

Comment: What do you mean you can't tell if you were able to install `Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP::TLS`? Open up a console and run `perl -e 'use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP::TLS;'`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perl cannot locate module in @INC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730715/perl-cannot-locate-module-in-inc)

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate - the OS are different so it's justified to keep these questions separate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the CPAN installation did not work. Provide more details, that is to say, the complete log of the installation attempt, if you decide to continue that way.

Otherwise just install the Ubuntu package [`libemail-sender-transport-smtp-tls-perl`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/libemail-sender-transport-smtp-tls-perl).